# Число делителей факториала

Tags: python, алгоритм, теория-чисел

я написала код по задаче:

```
По заданному натуральному числу N необходимо вычислить количество 
натуральных чисел, которые есть делителями N! (факториала числа N).

Например, при N=4, N!=4·3·2·1=24. Это число имеет следующие делители: 
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24. Таким образом, искомое количество составляет 8.

Напишите программу, которая по натуральному N, находит количество 
делителей его факториала.

Формат входных данных

Единственная строка входного файла содержит одно целое число N (1≤N≤45).

Формат выходных данных

Единственная строка выходного файла должна содержать одно целое 
число –найденное количество делителей числа N!

Примеры
входные данные
4
выходные данные
8

входные данные 
3
выходные данные 
4
```

Мой код:

```
from math import factorial
a=int(input())
n=factorial(a)
ans=0 
q=1
while q*q<n:
    if n%q==0:
        ans+=2
    q+=1
if q*q==n:
    ans+=1
print(ans)
```

Но на некоторых тестах проверяющей системы код работает слишком долго, помогите пожалуйста его оптимизировать!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подумайте вот о чём - для каждого очередного значения факториала `n!` нет необходимости заново искать все множители огромного числа, нужно только учесть следующее - `n!= (n-1)!*n`, и выяснить, как умножение на `n` изменит число множителей. А для этого достаточно разложить на **простые** множители сравнительно небольшое значение `n` и хранить **степени** уже имеющихся простых множителей, например, в словаре.

Формула для общего числа множителей будет такой:

```
F = (P2+1)*(P3+1)*(P5+1)*(P7+1)*(P11+1)...*(Pq+1)
```

где `Pk` - степень простого множителя `k`.

Например для 5!

```
 5! = 2^3 * 3 * 5
 Хранится  [3, 1, 1] или {2:3; 3:1; 5:1}
 F = 4 * 2 * 2 = 16
```

А для 6! на единицу увеличиваются степени двойки и тройки, так что список (в реальности словарь) степеней изменится так

```
 [4, 2, 1]) или  {2:4; 3:2; 5:1}
```

И ответ будет

```
 F = 5 * 3 * 2 = 30
```

Думаю, этой информации достаточно для решения

Пример нахождения степеней простых чисел:

```
from collections import Counter
def primes(n):
    res = Counter()
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        m = 0   #степень множителя
        while n % d == 0:
            m += 1
            n //= d
        if m:
            res[d]  = m
        d += 2 if d > 2 else 1   #после двойки идём по нечётным
    return res

print(primes(840))

Counter({2: 3, 3: 1, 5: 1, 7: 1})
```

Напомню ещё раз, что эту функцию применяем не к факториалу, а к его очередному сомножителю, а результат используется для обновления хранящихся степеней простых.

Answer (score 1):

Быстрое решение строится на двух идеях.

- Число делителей числа *n* можно вычислить по его разложению на простые множители.

  Пусть *n = p<sub>1</sub><sup>a<sub>1</sub></sup> p<sub>2</sub><sup>a<sub>2</sub></sup> p<sub>3</sub><sup>a<sub>3</sub></sup> …*, где *p<sub>i</sub>* - различные простые, a<sub>i</sub> - натуральные числа. Тогда число делителей *n* есть

  *σ<sub>0</sub>(n) = (a<sub>1</sub> + 1)(a<sub>2</sub> + 1)(a<sub>3</sub> + 1)…*

  Подробнее в статье [Функция делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).
- Разложение факториала в произведение простых строится без вычисления самого факториала.

  Простое число *p<sub>i</sub>* входит в разложение факториала *n!* в степени

  *a<sub>i</sub> = ⌊n / p<sub>i</sub>⌋ + ⌊n / p<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>⌋ + ⌊n / p<sub>i</sub><sup>3</sup>⌋ + …*

  Доказывается непосредственно. Подробности в статье [Факториал](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8).

Рецепт решения: найти все простые числа *p<sub>i</sub>*: *1 ≤ p<sub>i</sub> ≤ n*. Вычислить для них степени *a<sub>i</sub>*, добавить единицы, перемножить.

```
import math


def is_prime(n):
    return n >= 2 and all(n % d != 0 for d in range(2, n))


def factorial_exponent(n, p):
    # assuming prime p
    s = 0
    t = n // p
    while t > 0:
        s += t
        t //= p
    return s


def factorial_n_divisors(n):
    p = 1
    for i in range(n + 1):
        if is_prime(i):
            a = factorial_exponent(n, i)
            p *= a + 1
    return p


print(factorial_n_divisors(int(input())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 3 | python factorial-n-divisors.py 
> 4
>
> $ echo 4 | python factorial-n-divisors.py 
> 8
>
> $ echo 45 | python factorial-n-divisors.py 
> 819624960
>
> $ time echo 10000 | python factorial-n-divisors.py
> 6440227747...0000000000
>
> real  0m0.506s
> user  0m0.504s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```py
from math import factorial
n = factorial(int(input()))
sqrt = n**.5
ans = sqrt.is_integer()
sqrt = int(sqrt)
for i in range(2, sqrt):
    if n % i == 0:
        ans += 2
print(ans)
```

Comment: 3 -> False, 4 -> 4 (должно быть 8). Это не работает.